# Tear down Bridge.NET

Tags: javascript, bridge.net

We use a 3rd party library in some pages on our website. This library is dependent on a Bridge.NET generated JS module, so we load it to our site.

Apparently, the `bridge.min.js` module appends some properties to the `Object` prototype. In another page we have code that tries to calculate hashes of objects using the `object-hash` library. The `object-hash` takes into consideration all properties in the prototype chain, and ends up calling all properties that bridge injects. One of them throws an error and this crashes the page.

Since `bridge.min.js` and the interfering library aren't used in the same page, I thought maybe we can "tear down" the changes that bridge made to the Object prototype.

Is there an official way to do it? I can just `delete` those properties but it doesn't feel right to me.

Here's how the object prototype looks like after loading `bridge.min.js`
[image: Here's how the object prototype looks like after loading bridge.min.js]

Comment: > Those properties interfere with another library that we use in a different page

What library is Bridge conflicting with? What is the error?

Bridge adds a System` object is added to the document. The items in `$$inheritors` from your screenshot are items that inherit from `Object`, which everything does.

Comment: The library is `object-hash`, I edited the question. Thanks for the comment. Regarding the `$$inheritors` field, I understand, but is there a way to tell `bridge.js` "Okay, we're done using you, please clean up any variables you've put on the global scope"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and make bridge.min.js a module. This means it will only affect files that import it.

First, modify bridge.min.js:

Replace the `(this);` at the end of the file with `(globalThis);`

Remove the script tag which imports it and add `type="module"` to the files that import bridge.min.js.

Add `import 'bridge.min.js'`.

See the following code pen for an example: https://codepen.io/michaelcheers/pen/MWmWmWr